# Python CSV read-> write; remove and replace PLUS: end of line is JSON format

Tags: python, json, csv

I am having problems getting my Python script to do what I want.  It does not appear to be modifying my file.

I want to:

1. Read in a *.csv file that has the following format
   PropertyName::PropertyValue,…,PropertyName::PropertyValue,{ExtPropertyName::ExtPropertyValue},…,{ExtPropertyName:: ExtPropertyValue}
2. I want to remove PropertyName:: and leave behid just a column of the PropertyValue
3. I want to add a header line

I was trying to step through replacing the :: values with a comma, but cant seem to get this to work:

```
fin = csv.reader(open('infile', 'rb'), delimiter=',')
fout = open('outfile', 'w')
for row in fin:
   fout.write(','.join(','.join(item.split()) for item in row) + '::')
fout.close()
```

Any advice, whether on my first step problem, or to a bigger picture resolution is always appreciated. Thanks.

UPDATE/EDIT asked for by a person nice enough to review for me!

Here is the first line of the *.csv file (INPUT)

```
InnerDiameterOrWidth::0.1,InnerHeight::0.1,Length2dCenterToCenter::44.6743867864386,Length3dCenterToCenter::44.6768028159989,Length2dToInsideEdge::44.2678260053526,Length3dToInsideEdge::44.2717800813466,Length2dToOutsideEdge::44.6743867864386,Length3dToOutsideEdge::44.6768028159989,MinimumCover::0,MaximumCover::0,StartConnection::ImmxGisUtilityNetworkCommon.Connection,
```

In a perfect world here is what I would like my text file to look like (OUTPUT)

```
InnerDiameterOrWidth, InnerHeight, Length2dCenterToCenter,,,,,,,,,,,
0.1,0.1,44.6743867864386
```

so one header line and the values in column

**UPDATED** JSON Info

The end of each line has JSON formatted text:

```
{StartPoint::7858.35924983374[%2C]1703.69341358077[%2C]-3.075},{EndPoint::7822.85045874375[%2C]1730.80294308742[%2C]-3.53962362760298}
```

WHich I need to split into X Y Z and X Y Z with headers

Comment: Could you please update you question with some proper input and the expected output? BTW, welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks Fredrik, long time reader- first time poster!  Will update shortly.

Comment: What's your problem? And why you don't write the file with `csv.writer`?

Comment: the file has multiple delimiters and I cant seem to get the above code to work (response to wRAR).  Thank you for looking.

Comment: wRAR, sorry, I dont think I addressed your question.  Why not csv.writer?  Because I am a newbie and just learning Python for the first time......  Will look into it.

Comment: Martin has provided the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211160/parsing-text-file-with-json-like-object-into-csv

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this (assuming that each line has the same keys, and in the same order):

```
import csv

with open("diam.csv", "rb") as fin, open("diam_out.csv", "wb") as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
        split = [item.split("::") for item in line if item.strip()]
        if not split: # blank line
            continue
        keys, vals = zip(*split)
        if i == 0:
            # first line: write header
            writer.writerow(keys)
        writer.writerow(vals)
```

which produces

```
localhost-2:coding $ cat diam_out.csv 
InnerDiameterOrWidth,InnerHeight,Length2dCenterToCenter,Length3dCenterToCenter,Length2dToInsideEdge,Length3dToInsideEdge,Length2dToOutsideEdge,Length3dToOutsideEdge,MinimumCover,MaximumCover,StartConnection
0.1,0.1,44.6743867864386,44.6768028159989,44.2678260053526,44.2717800813466,44.6743867864386,44.6768028159989,0,0,ImmxGisUtilityNetworkCommon.Connection
```

I think most of that code should make sense, except maybe the `zip(*split)` trick: that basically transposes a sequence, i.e.

```
>>> s = [['a','1'],['b','2']]
>>> zip(*s)
[('a', 'b'), ('1', '2')]
```

so that the elements are now grouped together by their index (the first ones are all together, the second, etc.)

Comment: Thanks DSM.  I appreciate your taking the time to look at this.  WIll try it, and may take a while for me to digest it.  But above all, thank you for you time.

Comment: DSM, wow.  that was fast.  Seems to work great.  A question on this (I have 5 files that follow this format, and one that deviates from it only slightly in that it has the same format except for the last string of text, there is a second delimiter '[%2C]'  Can I add a second line of split = [item.split("[%2C]" for item in line if item.strip()] ??

Comment: {StartPoint::7858.35924983374[%2C]1703.69341358077[%2C]-3.075},{EndPoint::7822.85045874375[%2C]1730.80294308742[%2C]-3.53962362760298} here is the end of the file, it has coordinates separated by [%2C] and need to have X Y Z header

Comment: Looks as though it is similar to the JSON format:      http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html