# parsing text file with JSON-like object into CSV

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a text file containing key-value pairs, with the last two key-value pairs containing JSON-like objects that I would like to split out into columns and write with the other values, using the keys as column headings.  The first three rows of the data file `input.txt` look like this:

```
InnerDiameterOrWidth::0.1,InnerHeight::0.1,Length2dCenterToCenter::44.6743867864386,Length3dCenterToCenter::44.6768028159989,Tag::<NULL>,{StartPoint::7858.35924983374[%2C]1703.69341358077[%2C]-3.075},{EndPoint::7822.85045874375[%2C]1730.80294308742[%2C]-3.53962362760298}
InnerDiameterOrWidth::0.1,InnerHeight::0.1,Length2dCenterToCenter::57.8689351603823,Length3dCenterToCenter::57.8700464193429,Tag::<NULL>,{StartPoint::7793.52927597915[%2C]1680.91224357457[%2C]-3.075},{EndPoint::7822.85045874375[%2C]1730.80294308742[%2C]-3.43363070193163}
InnerDiameterOrWidth::0.1,InnerHeight::0.1,Length2dCenterToCenter::68.7161350545728,Length3dCenterToCenter::68.7172034962765,Tag::<NULL>,{StartPoint::7858.35924983374[%2C]1703.69341358077[%2C]-3.075},{EndPoint::7793.52927597915[%2C]1680.91224357457[%2C]-3.45819643838485}
```

and we eventually came up with something that worked, but there must be a much better way:

```
import csv
with open('input.txt', 'rb') as fin, open('output.csv', 'wb') as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
        mysplit = [item.split('::') for item in line if item.strip()]
        if not mysplit: # blank line
            continue
        keys, vals = zip(*mysplit)
        start_vals = [item.split('[%2C]') for item in mysplit[-2]]
        end_vals = [item.split('[%2C]') for item in mysplit[-1]]
        a=list(keys[0:-2])
        a.extend(['start1','start2','start3','end1','end2','end3'])
        b=list(vals[0:-2])
        b.append(start_vals[1][0])
        b.append(start_vals[1][1])
        b.append(start_vals[1][2][:-1])
        b.append(end_vals[1][0])
        b.append(end_vals[1][1])
        b.append(end_vals[1][2][:-1])
        if i == 0:
            # if first line: write header
            writer.writerow(a)
        writer.writerow(b)
```

which produces the output file `output.csv` that looks like this

```
InnerDiameterOrWidth,InnerHeight,Length2dCenterToCenter,Length3dCenterToCenter,Tag,start1,start2,start3,end1,end2,end3
0.1,0.1,44.6743867864386,44.6768028159989,<NULL>,7858.35924983374,1703.69341358077,-3.075,7822.85045874375,1730.80294308742,-3.53962362760298
0.1,0.1,57.8689351603823,57.8700464193429,<NULL>,7793.52927597915,1680.91224357457,-3.075,7822.85045874375,1730.80294308742,-3.43363070193163
0.1,0.1,68.7161350545728,68.7172034962765,<NULL>,7858.35924983374,1703.69341358077,-3.075,7793.52927597915,1680.91224357457,-3.45819643838485
```

We don't want to write code like this in the future.

What is the best way to read data like this?

Comment: There is nothing JSON-like about that input format. The only think remotely related are the curly braces and commas, but there the comparison ends.

Comment: I think someone asked a question just like this a couple days ago, I'll try to find it.  Or maybe this is the continuation of that question? Edit: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190260/python-csv-read-write-remove-and-replace-plus-end-of-line-is-json-format/15190741)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use:

```
from itertools import chain
import csv

_header_translate = {
    'StartPoint': ('start1', 'start2', 'start3'),
    'EndPoint': ('end1', 'end2', 'end3')
}

def header(col):
    header = col.strip('{}').split('::', 1)[0]
    return _header_translate.get(header, (header,))

def cleancolumn(col):
    col = col.strip('{}').split('::', 1)[1]
    return col.split('[%2C]')

def chainedmap(func, row):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(map(func, row)))

with open('input.txt', 'rb') as fin, open('output.csv', 'wb') as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if not i:  # first row, write header first
            writer.writerow(chainedmap(header, row))
        writer.writerow(chainedmap(cleancolumn, row))
```

The `cleancolumn` method takes any of your columns and returns a tuple (possibly with only one value) after removing the braces, removing everything before the first `::` and splitting on the embedded 'comma'. By using `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` we turn the series of tuples generated from the columns into one list again for the csv writer.

When handling the first line we generate one header row from the same columns, replacing the `StartPoint` and `EndPoint` headers with the 6 expanded headers.

Comment: Nice answer. Any reason you prefer 'if not i' over 'if i == 0'? To me, you're not asking "does it exist?", you're checking if it is the value 0.

Comment: @daveydave400: numeric 0 is always false in Python. So are empty sequences and collections (dict, set, list, tuple, string, etc.). It's easier and cleaner in my eyes.

Comment: I know that it's accurate and that empty sequences evaluate to false, I just personally prefer the "== X" when actually checking for a value and was wondering if you had another reason besides preference. When I check for empty sequences I use the "not X", if checking for None "is None" or "is not None".

Comment: @daveydave400: There is a different reason to explicitly test for `None`; you may want to allow `0` but not `None`. Here there is no ambiguity; `enumerate()` starts at 0.

Comment: Martijn, I learned so much from your solution.  This is the best thing about SO.  Plus it works!  Thanks so much.  -Rich